# How to make list-packages Help for dependency package show the dependee packages?

Tags: package, package-repositories, list-packages

I use `use-package` to require the `boxquote` package into my GNU Emacs 26.3 running on Ubuntu 19.10, like this:

```
 (use-package boxquote
   :ensure t)
```

In the `list-packages` buffer, I see the `boxquote` package:

```
boxquote           20170802.1117 dependency            Quote text with a semi-box.
```

Typing `?` on that line, reveals:

```
boxquote is a dependency package.

     Status: Installed in ‘boxquote-20170802.1117/’ (unsigned).
    Version: 20170802.1117
     Commit: 7e47e0e2853bc1215739b2e28f260e9eed93b2c5
    Summary: Quote text with a semi-box.
   Requires: cl-lib-0.5
   Homepage: https://github.com/davep/boxquote.el
   Keywords: quoting 
Other versions: 20170802.1117 (melpa).
```

If Emacs knows it is a "dependency package", shouldn't it show `Required By:` or similar? I say that because another "dependency package", `async` does show this line in its **Help** buffer:

```
async              20200113.1745 dependency            Asynchronous processing in Emacs
...
async is a dependency package.

     Status: Installed in ‘async-20200113.1745/’ (unsigned).
    Version: 20200113.1745
    Summary: Asynchronous processing in Emacs
   Requires: emacs-24.3
Required by: magit-popup-2.13.0, with-editor-20200217.1015, magit-20200318.1224, helm-core-20200306.1417, helm-20200325.757
   Homepage: https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async
   Keywords: async 
Other versions: 1.9.3 (installed), 20200113.1745 (melpa), 1.9.3 (gnu).
```

An [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37711/15483) to [What does dependency mean in the Status field of a package shown in list-packages](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/37058/15483) says:

> Packages which were explicitly installed by the user are identified as such by adding them to package-selected-packages.

Viewing the current value of `package-selected-packages` shows:

```
package-selected-packages is a variable defined in ‘package.el’.
Its value is
(org git-timemachine htmlize elpy ggtags graphql helm helm-pydoc magit magit-popup ob-async org-plus-contrib use-package)
Original value was nil
```

So I'm puzzled: I am using use-package so it is kind of "selected" by me, no?

Also, further searching turns up a [comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43638/confusing-elpa-types/43639#comment66963_43639) to an [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/43639/15483) to [Confusing ELPA types](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/43638/15483) which says:

> I wouldn't expect the 'required' package to list all the packages that require it - how would you know who else might require your code? More likely Emacs auto-generates the 'required-by' attribute during installation. If it's not filled in, perhaps something went (mildly) wrong during installation. – Tyler Jul 16 '18

"how would you know who else might require your code" is exactly what I'm after, so that I can trace it back ultimately to a `require` or a `use-package` call in my own setup, to determine if it is safe to remove. Is there something wrong with my use of `use-package`?

Comment: Good, clear question.

Comment: My guess: the value of `package-selected-packages` needs to be persistent across Emacs sessions to work, any package outside `package-selected-packages` is *dependency*, even no other package requires it, for example, if you delete your custom.el and restart Emacs, every package is dependency?

Comment: @xuchunyang If any package not listed inside `package-selected-packages` is a dependency, then something should be tracking what packages those depend upon, not leave the user guessing as to which other packages are the dependee packages. The issue is that the `list-packages` is not showing the specific packages in the `Required by` field.